# Enumerating updated lists

Tags: vb.net, linq, enumerate

How can I enumerate throw updating lists.
For example, I have the following code:

```
For I as integer = 0 to MyList.Count-1
.......
.......
Next
```

when I run this loop the (MyList) is updated from Another source, then I will get an error "Collection was modified."

I don't want to stop the update of the (MyList), and also I need an instance of the list separated from the updated one. 
For example: if the (MyList) contains 10 items before I start the For...Next loop and throw the loop the (MyList) updated from outer source to be 12 items, I steel need to run the For....Next for the 10 items only and I don't want the extra new 2 items. and at the same time I don't want to lose these new 2 items.

I decided to have a copy from (MyList) by the following code:

```
 m.ToList.AsEnumerable
```

because (MyList) is 'iEnumerable(Of DataRow)', but also I've gotten the same error "Collection was modified"

Any Idea??

Comment: Try to create new one List instead of updating

Comment: If u update your list from one thread and still want to have original one intact, how would you manage the underlying data source?

Comment: what you can do is like create a new instance of the list which you want to iterate through.

Comment: Show the code you are using as `For I as integer = 0 to MyList.Count-1 : Next` is not enumerating `MyList`.  Enumeration involves using an `IEnumerator` obtained by calling `MyList.GetEnumerator`.  You either do this explicitly or implicitly (by using a `For Each item In MyList : Next Item` block).  It is the `IEnumerator` that throws the "Collection was modified" error.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to enumerate the list while other threads might be changing it, one option is to just copy it (in C#, as I'm not fluent in VB):

```
var list = new List<int>(MyList);
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    // process your original items 
    // regardless of whether someone adds or removes from 'MyList'
}
```

Comment: I guess that List constructor still enumerates the enumerable. Maybe try some of concurrent collections?